# Htaccess with several Rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got to write hyaccess rules so that it allows a few IP addresses to be able to view the site and others not.

Here's my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !82\.240\.138\.168
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I want the ip 82.240.138.168 to skip the redirection to the maintenance page and to be able to view my index.php page and apply the following rules :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I've tried several solutions but it didn't work. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: From what I understand, you want only to allow users with that specific IP to browse normally, and redirect everyone else to `index.php`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 No. people with specific ip should bypass the maintenance page and be able to view index.php